# Why is assertEquals(Object[], Object[]) from JUnit 4 deprecated?

Tags: java, junit, assert

Eclipse is giving me a warning that says that the method `assertEquals(Object[], Object[])` from the type `Assert` is deprecated. I am using JUnit 4.

I wrote the following code in Eclipse:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class Generics { 
    public <T> T[] genericArraySwap(T[] list, int pos1, int pos2) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void genericArraySwapTest() {
        Integer[] IntegerList = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};        
        Assert.assertEquals(new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, 4, 3}, genericArraySwap(IntegerList, 3, 4));
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why this method is deprecated or what method I should use instead?

Comment: You should use `assertArrayEquals(Object[] expecteds, Object[] actuals)` instead of `assertEquals(Object[], Object[])`.

Comment: "Deprecated. use assertArrayEquals" I'd guess it is deprecated because it is too easy to call `assertEquals(Object, Object[])` by mistake.

Comment: Thanks, didn't saw that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my assertEquals() deprecated in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274030/why-is-my-assertequals-deprecated-in-junit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's deprecated because of the lack of expressivity of the Java type system.

Whereas all of the other `assertEquals` methods will compare the parameters using `==` (for primitives) or `equals` (for reference types), you don't want to use either to compare arrays: all arrays are subtypes of `Object` (i.e. they are reference types), and don't override `equals`, so using `assertEquals` to compare arrays will check whether the two arrays are identical.

Instead, you should invoke `assertArrayEquals`, which compares whether the arrays have the same length, and if so, whether the corresponding array elements are equal.

Ideally, you would be able to specify parameter types like this:

```
assertEquals(T, T)
```

where `T` is "any subtype of `Object`, except for arrays". But you simply can't do that in Java; even if there were a way to express such a constraint, you couldn't prevent the method being called with array, because you can always upcast them to `Object`s.

The only thing that you can do is to:

- Provide an overload which accepts `Object`s
- Provide overloads which accept more specific types, and mark these overloads `@Deprecated`. To cover all array types, you need 9 overloads (8 for each of the primitive array types; 1 for `Object[]`, which covers all other reference types).

This doesn't prevent you from invoking `assertEquals(T[], T[])`, but it does highlight that there is a problem there, via compiler warnings;  yellow squiggles in Eclipse; etc.

Of course, this won't help in the case that you've upcast the arrays to `Object`; but you won't, in most cases, unless you really intend to invoke that specific method.